# graphviz drawing graph vertically

Tags: graphviz

I am using graphviz to draw directed graphs . Now thing is that although I am able to generate graph correctly the graph is designed horizontally which is not according to my requirements . So, how can I draw directed graphs vertically
Please help me with this

Comment: What is your [rankdir](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:rankdir) setting?

Comment: @Anders Lindahl I haven't dfined rankdir properties . please suggest me what modification I need to perform

Comment: Show an example of your graph description, and the command you use to render it.

Comment: digraph G {
graph [ bgcolor=lightgray, resolution=128, fontname=Arial, fontcolor=blue, 
                       fontsize=10 ];
                 node [ fontname=Arial, fontcolor=blue, fontsize=10];
                 edge [ fontname=Helvetica, fontcolor=red, fontsize=10 ];
"http://arunachaltourism.com/" -> "http://www.webcomindia.biz/profile.php";
"http://arunachaltourism.com/#" -> "http://arunachaltourism.com/";
"http://arunachaltourism.com/aalo.php" -> "http://arunachaltourism.com/";}

Answer (score 27):

Given the following script, which I've extracted from the comments to the question and edited to make it run successfully by removing some extraneous semicolons:

```
digraph G { 
    graph [ bgcolor=lightgray, resolution=128, fontname=Arial, fontcolor=blue, fontsize=10 ]; 
    node [ fontname=Arial, fontcolor=blue, fontsize=10]; 
    edge [ fontname=Helvetica, fontcolor=red, fontsize=10 ]; 
    "arunachaltourism.com/" -> "webcomindia.biz/profile.php"; 
    "arunachaltourism.com/#" -> "arunachaltourism.com/";
    "arunachaltourism.com/aalo.php" -> "arunachaltourism.com/";
}
```

I called the script `x.dot`. Now, running:

```
dot x.dot -Tjpg -o x.jpg
```

... produces:

[image]

... because the default is `rankdir=TB`. Inserting:

```
rankdir=LR
```

... as the second line of the script and running the script through `dot` again gives:

[image]

Thus, it isn't clear to me why the graph might have been drawn horizontally the first time, but you will be able to see how using `rankdir` can make the graph come out either horizontally or vertically.

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for

Comment: Perfect answer; changing the rank direction helped.

Comment: default is TB, not BT

Comment: Thanks @bsmk. Well spotted! I've edited my answer to correct it.

Comment: Doesn't work if the graph is more than about 6 or 7 nodes deep. After that, it only spreads horizontally, never vertically. (with dot layout engine)

Answer (score 23):

(old question, but why not!)

You can as well run:

```
dot -Grankdir=LR -Tpng myfile.dot -ogeneratedpng.png
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use `rankdir` as a property in the dot file:

```
digraph G {
     rankdir=LR;  //left to right
     //B bottom  T top  L left R right
      start->a1;
      a1 -> b3;
      b2 -> a3;
      a3 -> a0;
      a3 -> end;
      b3 -> end;
    }
```

The script generate the following graph from left to right:

You can try the script  [online](https://dreampuf.github.io/GraphvizOnline/) 
[image]